# can we apply search to tablview of array getting from json parsing

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I'm searching in `tableView` but `NSDictionry` has no member item it is not filtering search

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {arrFilterLocation = searchText.isEmpty ? arrInrestLocation:arrInrestLocation.filter({ (item:String) -> Bool in
        return item.range(of: searchText,options: .caseInsensitive ,range: nil,locale: nil) != nil
    })
   TabelView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/472-uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: You are encouraged not to use `NSDictionary`. Parse the JSON into structs. It makes searching so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `arrFilterLocation` and `arrInrestLocation` are both `arrays` of `String`, i.e.

```
var arrInrestLocation: [String]
var arrFilterLocation: [String]
```

You can simply use `contains(_:)` on each `string` to `filter` out all the `strings` in `arrInrestLocation` that contains `searchText`

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    arrFilterLocation = searchText.isEmpty ? arrInrestLocation : arrInrestLocation.filter({ $0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) })
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: `$0.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil` is much more efficient than  `$0.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())`

Comment: both array of NSDictionary.

Comment: First of all use Dictionary instead of NSDictionary. Also, add an example of the dictionary you’re using in which you want to search the words.